# Enabling python3 on vim in Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, vim, python3

I have vim installed and it is configured with `+python3/dyn`. If I run `vim --noplugin` I can use `py3`. However with my plugins enabled, I get the following error:

```
E837: This Vim cannot execute :py3 after using :python
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

I suspect that one of the plugins loads python2 and therefore defines which python version is being used ([similar to this vim-bootstrap issue](https://github.com/avelino/vim-bootstrap/issues/156)). The problem is I don't know which.

How can I use python3 with my vim version?

---

**Plungins Installed**

The following plugins are installed with Vundle:

```
 60 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 61 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
 62 "Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
 63 Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
 64 Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
 65 Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
 66 Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 67 Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
 68 Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
 69 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
 70 Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
 71 "Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
 72 Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
 73 Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
 74 Bundle 'klen/python-mode'
 75 Plugin 'jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv'
```

**Trying to make Python3 the default/preferred version**

I have tried to make python3 the preferred alternative by running:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

vim (or one of the plugins) still uses python2.7 and I get the same errors as above.

**My vim version**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun  2 2016 10:02:17)
Included patches: 1-1868
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that simply executing `has('python')` in an if-statement causes python3 to be unavailable when vim was compiled with both python/dyn and python3/dyn. The simplest solution is probably just to add something like

```
if exists('py2') && has('python')
elseif has('python3')
endif
```

to your .vimrc before Vundle loads anything. Then, if you ever need to use python 2 instead you can just start vim with `vim --cmd 'let py2 = 1'`.

Alternatively, I looked through your plugins and managed to find 3 which do `has('python')` before `has('python3')`:

1. YouCompleteMe: I know you have this commented out, but it's how I stumbled across this question so it may lead someone else here. On line 36 of YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim, make python3 get checked for first: `elseif !has( 'python3' ) && !has( 'python' )`.
2. python-mode: If you look in python-mode/plugin/pymode.vim, around line 275 there's the "has" if-statement, you'll notice you can actually set a global variable `g:_uspy` to force a certain version to be used. So, either put `g:_uspy = ':py3'` in your .vimrc before the Vundle stuff or edit the if-statement in pymode.vim.
3. vim-virtualenv: Same deal as YCM, reverse the conditions of the if-statement on line 10 of vim-virtualenv/plugin/virtualenv.vim.

Of course, you really only need to fix the first one that's loaded if you do it this way.

Comment: The if statement works brilliantly! Thanks heaps. Also for searching the vim plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have python 3 installed...

Instead of running `:python`, use `:python3` or `:py3`

Try this code in Vim and it will run in python 3

```
:python3 print("Hello world")
```

For more info:

```
:help python3
```